# How do I resize the desktop icons in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: icons, resize

How do I resize the desktop icons in Ubuntu 15.04?

I ran `/usr/bin/nautilus` in terminal

Nautilus did not open. The icon size changed when I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 15.04, and I wish to change them back.

Comment: Does just running `nautilus` open it? Do you mean desktop icons or folder icons? Try holding Ctrl + Scrolling up.

Comment: I cannot open Nautilus.  I want to resize my desktop icons

Comment: How have you tried to open it?

Comment: What happens when you try opening it - What error messages etc are producded?

Comment: I typed /usr/bin/Nautilus on the line next to the magnifying glass on my Chromium Browser.  A menu opened.

Comment: I have also looked for Nautilus in the Ubuntu Software Center

Answer (score 1):

Right-clic on the icon, then choose "Resize the icon...".

You can also run dconf-editor and search for schemas like :

org.gnome.desktop.interface

and

org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view ?

Comment: I right clicled on the icon.  I selected Resize icon.  The icon size did not change.  No other menus opened.  The resize option became dulled.

Answer (score 0):

To open nautilus, try pressing the super(windows) key and type in "files".  Click on the picture of a chest of drawers that says "files". If that doesn't work, simply type `nautilus` into terminal(control-alt-t). (If neither of those work, I have no idea what's going on) If nautilus did open, go to the Edit menu, and select Preferences. Click on the "views" tab, and then look at the setting "icon view defaults". Change that until your icons are back to their normal size.

Comment: I opened the super (windows) key and typed "files." I clicked on the picture of a chest of drawers.  A window opened to a number of folders that I created.   I also typed the words, Nautilus, Applications and Accessories all without success

Comment: In that window with the folders, see if there is an edit menu (hover your mouse over the bar at the top and the menus should appear) and select preferences. Then click on the "views" tab and edit "icon view defaults".

Comment: The preferences  option should be under the edit menu. (sorry, I wasn't clear before)